# 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' in System.ServiceModel.dll: Procedure not present

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

Had a Web Service working for years, then one day it started blowing up in Production:

A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
Additional information: Procedure 'GetDoorToDoorRatesRequest' not present.

Errors out every time.

The WSDL shows that the procedure still exists and firing a test SOAP XML envelope at the procedure manually gets a valid response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case the Exception was misleading:

1. The class in question was a Request Model class, not really a Procedure.
2. It was in fact present.
3. The real problem was it had changed in format; the server-side we were calling had changed the properties on the Request class without changing the major or even minor version number, and without warning us. This meant a broken Production call and a confusing error message.

The solution was to update the Service Reference from the WSDL and recompile. Interestingly none of the existing properties we were using had changed or been removed, so the exception was basically just in our way.

Hope this helps someone else!